# Paypal webhook integration

Tags: api, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the Webhooks from Paypal, but after sending a Mock Hook it triggers the Hook the whooooole time. Every like 5 min or so:

```
public function paypalhooked(){


    $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
    $event_json = json_decode($input, TRUE);

    AppController::mailsend($event_json, 'admin_paypalwebhook', 'Subject', 'info@xxxxx',0 , '');

}
```

What to do?